# Why is it called the *Inverse* Galois Problem?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, galois-theory, math-history, open-problem

This is just a very quick question and hopefully not poorly received.

**Question:** Why is it called the *inverse* galois problem?

The very brief statement given on wikipedia says

> Is every finite group the Galois group of a Galois extension of the rational numbers?

That is, are all finite groups isomorphic to a Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ for some field $K$?

Comment: Extensions of rational numbers will produce groups via the Galois Correspondence.  We want to know whether the reverse is true:  Every group produces an extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding for this terminology has always been that the "usual" Galois "problem", as it were, is to find the Galois group given the field; thus, the "inverse" problem is to find a field given the Galois group.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your answer.